# Atomically updating the count of a DB field in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

*Note* - This question expands on an answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34014916/2490003).

I'm importing a file into my DB by chunking it up into smaller groups and spawning background jobs to import each chunk (of 100 rows).

I want a way to track progress of how many chunks have been imported so far, so I had planned on each job incrementing a DB field by 1 when it's done so I know how many have processed so far.

This has a potential situation of two parallel jobs incrementing the DB field by 1 simultaneously and overwriting each other.

What's the best way to avoid this condition and ensure an atomic parallel operation? The linked post above suggests using Redis, which is one good approach. For the purposes of this question I'm curious if there is an alternate way to do it using persistent storage.

I'm using ActiveRecord in Rails with Postgres as my DB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to NOT incrementing a DB field by 1, instead, create a DB record with for each job with a job id. There are two benefits:

1. You can count the number of records to let you know how many have processed without worrying about parallel operations.
2. You can also add some necessary logs into each job record and easily debug when any of the jobs fails when importing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a postgresql sequence.

See [CREATE SEQUENCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) and [Sequence Manipulation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-sequence.html).
Especially `nextval()`:

> Advance the sequence object to its next value and return that value. This is done atomically: **even if multiple sessions execute nextval concurrently, each will safely receive a distinct sequence value**.